# How to install ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, installation

I would like to install ffmpeg for my site. But I am using shared server so the hosting will not provide this

Could any one please help me to install ffmpeg(I am not using Linux environment)

Comment: what do you mean install ffmpeg in PHP ? you want to install it to your server via PHP ? You can't, as you do not have the rights, I believe.

Comment: @Johm Sanjay:  Did you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172916/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-wampserver-2-0-windows-xp ?

Comment: Just a suggestion but instead of telling us which environment you _aren't_ using, tell us which one you _are_...

Comment: You can try downloading a static or shared build from [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and pointing your scripts to use the resulting binary or libraries.

Answer (score 3):

If the host won't allow it then I'm afraid there is no way around it. Try upgrading to a better host or purchasing a VPS that will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

May be below will help you for the same...

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/install-ffmpeg
(This is for linux environment. So in your case its not useful. but may help you in future.)

[FFMPEG PHP does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607062/ffmpeg-php-does-not-seem-to-work)
(Similar problem with a solution)

http://vexxhost.com/blog/2006/12/20/what-ffmpeg-php-can-do-and-how-to-use-the-most-out-of-it/

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is also in the collection.. http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Installing_FFmpeg_and_FFmpeg-php

Answer (score 0):

you can use, but can't install ffmpeg with PHP. you have to ask your hosting provider to provide it for you (but i don't think they will)

Answer (score 0):

Fun the following command to install ffmpeg :

I hope the url will help you ,

http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm